# is there a way to use both int and string in a statement

Tags: c++, string, integer

i want to allow the user to input both ints and strings in a single statement, so if they type a number they input an int, while if they input a string value they input a string.

The code I want to use it for, basically, I want to allow the user to set a string's value as a number, and use it in the calculations, e.g `A = 5, A + 5 = 10`. If you need more info on what I'm asking, comment the details you need.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI   3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989

#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

// cout<<" enter second operator: "//
// cin>> oprator;
// if (oprator == '+'){cout<<"enter third number: ";
// cin>>num3;}
// if (oprator == '*'){cout<<"enter third number: ";
// cin>>num3;}
// if (oprator == '/'){cout<<"enter third number: ";
// cin>>num3;}
// if (oprator == '^'){cout<<"enter third number: ";
// cin>>num3;}
// if (oprator == '-'){cout<<"enter third number: ";
// cin>>num3;}//
string againmessage = " would you like to go again (y/n) ";
string modechange = " would you like to stay in this mode (y/n) ";
string areais = "area of the shape is: ";
string letter;
double a;
double num1;
double i;
double b;
double c3 = 299792458;
double c3sq = 89875517873681764;
double a2 = pow(a,2);
double b2 = pow(b,2);
int mc;
vector<double> numbers{i,b};
    
int E = 10000;
    
double num2;
    
double pyth (double){
    double ans = sqrt(num1*num1+num2*num2);
    return ans;
}
    
double ans = num1 + num2;
    
int num;
int numalt;
int numaltt;
    
//int nums [] = {srand(time(0));rand();}
    
double letterinto(double)
{ 
    double turninto = num2 = num1;
    return turninto;
}
    
double num3;
    
double times(double)
{
    double result = num1 * num2;
    return result;
}

double square(double)
{
    double result = num1 * num1;
    return result;
}

double addition(double)
{
    double answer = num1 + num2 + num3;
    return answer;
}

string name;
string oprator;

void sayHi(string name)
{
    cout << "Hello " << name;
}

double factorial(double n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
    
int getmode(int mchoice)
{
    switch (mchoice)
    {
        case 0:{
            double _finite = pow(2, 1023);
            char again = 'y';

            while (again == 'y')
            {
                if (num1 > _finite)
                {
                    cout<<"error: number is too big";
                }
                else
                {
                    // if (num1 = 'a';){cout<<"-->";cin>>num2;oprator = '>';}
                    cout << "hello enter first number : ";
                    cin >> numbers[i];
                    cout << "enter operator: ";
                    cin>> oprator;

                    if (oprator == "+" ||oprator == "*" ||oprator == "/" ||oprator == "^" ||oprator == "-"|| oprator == "x"||oprator == "X")
                    {
                        cout << "enter second number: ";
                        cin >> numbers[i-1];
                    }

                    if (oprator == "+")
                    {
                        cout << " the answer is!: \n"
                            <<numbers[i]+numbers[i-1]<< endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "=")
                    {
                        cin>>letter;
                        cout<<letter<<" = "<<numbers[i]<<endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "*"||oprator == "x"||oprator == "X")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: \n" <<numbers[i] * numbers[i-1]<< endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "/")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: " <<numbers[i] / numbers[i-1]<<" and the remainder is "<<fmod(numbers[i],numbers[i-1])<< endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "^")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: " << pow(numbers[i], numbers[i-1]) << endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "sqrt")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: " << sqrt(numbers[i]) << endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "-")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: " << numbers[i] - numbers[i-1] << endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "!")
                    {
                        cout << "the answer is!: " << factorial(numbers[i]) << endl;
                    }
                    else if (oprator == "LOG"|| oprator == "log")
                    {
                        cout<<"the answer is "<<log(numbers[i])<<endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        cout<<"invalid operator";
                    }
    
                    cout<< againmessage;
                    cin >> again;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 1:{
            cout<<" welcome to the units converter"<<endl;
            cout<<"choose conversion mode, 1 = binary, 2 = hex, 3 = octal";

            int getcon;
            cin>>getcon;

            switch(getcon)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    char again = 'y';
                    while(again == 'y'){
                        cout<<"enter number you want to convert to binary: ";

                        cin>> num;
                        int nums = num;
                        int dig = 0;
                        while (nums != 0)
                        {
                            dig++;
                            nums = nums / 10;
                        }
                        if(dig <= 4){
                            cout<<bitset<8>(num)<<endl;
                        }
                        else if(dig <= 8){
                            cout<<bitset<16>(num)<<endl;
                        }
                        cout<<againmessage;
                        cin>>again;
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 2:
                {
                    char again = 'y';
                    while(again == 'y'){
                        cout<<"enter number you want to convert to hexadecimal: ";
                        cin>> num;
                        cout<<hex<<num<<endl;
                        cout<<againmessage;
                        cin>>again;
                    }
                }
                break;

                case 3:
                {
                    char again = 'y';
                    while(again == 'y'){
                        cout<<"enter number you want to convert to octaldecimal: ";
                        cin>> num;
                        cout<<oct<<num<<endl;
                        cout<<againmessage;
                        cin>>again;
                    }
                }
                break;

                default:
                {
                    cout<<"either unimplemented or invalid system";
                }
            }//other cases
        }//unitconvcase
        break;

        default:
        {
            cout<<"either unimplemented or invalid digit or letter";
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            char again = 'y';
            while (again == 'y'){
                cout<<"welcome to the physics caculator, choose mode: 1 = pythagoras, 2 = energy calculator(work in progress)\n";
                int getmode;
                cin>> getmode;
                switch(getmode){
                    case 1:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y'){
                            double a;
                            double b;
                            double c;

                            cout << "Enter first number";
                            cin >> a;

                            cout << "Enter second number ";
                            cin >> b;

                            double a2 = pow(a, 2);
                            double b2 = pow(b, 2);
                            c = sqrt(a2 + b2);
                            double c2 = pow(c,2);

                            if(b != sqrt(c2 - a2)||a!= sqrt(c2 - b2))
                            {
                                cout<<"not a right angle triangle!";
                                cout<<againmessage;
                                cin>>again;
                            }
                            else
                                cout << "Hypotenuse is " << c <<endl;

                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }
    
                    case 2:{
                        int getfst;
                        cout<<"choose which form of formula; 1: static object/n 2: object with momentum";
                        cin>>getfst;
                        switch(getfst){
                            case 1:
                                cout<<"enter mass: ";
                                cin>>num1;
                                cout<<"E = "<<num1 * c3sq<<" joules ";
                                break;
    
                            case 2:{
                                again == 'y';
                                while (again == 'y'){
                                    cout<<"enter mass of the object";
                                    cin>>num1;
                                    cout<<"enter speed of the object";
                                    cin>>num2;
                                    double momentum = num1 * num2;
                                    double num4 = num1 * c3sq;
                                    cout<<"E^2 = "<<pow(num4,2) + pow(momentum * c3,2);
                                    cout<<"\nE = "<<sqrt(pow(num4,2) + pow(momentum * c3,2));
                                    cout<<againmessage;
                                    cin>>again;
                                }
                            }
                        }//static or non static
                    }

                    cout<<modechange;
                    cin>>again;
                }
            }
        }//physics calculator
        break;

        case 3:{
            char again = 'y';
            while(again == 'y')
            {
                cout<<"welcome to the area calculator";
                cout<<"choose which mode. 1: triangle\n 2:square\n 3:rectangle\n 4:circle\n 5: parallelogram\n 6:trapezoid\n 7:kite\n";
                int getshape;
                cin>> getshape;
                switch(getshape){
                    case 1:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while (again == 'y'){
                            cout<<"enter base length";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<"enter height ";
                            cin>>num2;
                            cout<<areais<<num1 * num2 / 2;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        };
                    }//triangle
                    break;

                    case 2:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y'){
                            cout<<"enter side";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<areais<<pow(num1,2);
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//square
                    break;

                    case 3:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y'){
                            cout<<"enter size of length";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<"enter size of breadth";
                            cin>>num2;
                            cout<<areais<<num1 * num2;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//rectangle
                    break;

                    case 4:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y')
                        {
                            cout<<"enter radius";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<pow(num1,2) * M_PI;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//circle
                    break;

                    case 5:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y'){
                            cout<<" enter base ";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<"enter length";
                            cin>>num2;
                            cout<<areais<<num1 * num2;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//parallelogram
                    break;

                    case 6:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y'){
                            cout<<"enter size of base 1";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<"enter size of base 2";
                            cin>>num2;
                            cout<<"enter height";
                            cin>>num3;
                            cout<<areais<<(num1 + num2) * num3 /2;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//trapezoid
                    break;

                    case 7:{
                        char again = 'y';
                        while(again == 'y')
                        {
                            cout<<"enter diagonal 1";
                            cin>>num1;
                            cout<<"enter diagonal 2";
                            cin>>num2;
                            cout<<(num1 + num2) /2;
                            cout<<againmessage;
                            cin>>again;
                        }
                    }//kite

                    cout<<modechange;
                }//switch

                cin>>again;
            }
        }//area calc simple
    }//important line this is for breaks
}
    
int main()
{
    cout<<"type n or any other digit for it to work: except 'y'";

    string again = "n";
    cin>>again;

    while(again == "y"){
        cout<<"enter number";
        oprator = "+";
        if(oprator == "+"){
            cin>>numbers[i];
            i--;
            cin>>oprator;
            cin>>numbers[i-1];
            i--;
            vector<int> sum = {numbers[i]+numbers[i-1]};
            double bo = 0;
            bo++;
        }

        vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        v1.push_back(9);

        cout<<v1.capacity()<<endl;
        cout<<v1.size()<<endl;

        v1.shrink_to_fit();

        cout<<v1.capacity()<<endl;

        v1.insert(v1.begin() + 5, 5);

        cout<<v1[0];

        cin>>again;
    }

    while(again != "y"){
        cout<<"hello choose mode:\n 0:normal \n 1:digit converter\n 2:formulas\n 3:shape's area\n";

        int x;
        cin>>x;

        getmode(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: take the whole line as string then parse it

Comment: @asmmo not exactly what i meant

Comment: This is not a minimal example. Also, follow @asmmo's advice and input everything as strings.

Comment: @Tanveer Badar if i input everything as a string, how would I plus them together?

Comment: While you're editing, please remove the excessive vertical whitespace, use proper indenting, and add whitespace between your operators.  This will help your code be readable to humans.  Consider simplifying your example to show the bare minimum.  As currently written, it's a large program that for the most part is not representative of the problem you're asking about.

Comment: _"how would I plus them together"_ -- you extract the integer parts from the string by _parsing_ it.  When you detect a token that looks like an integer, you can mark it as such and process it that way.  When you detect a token that is an operator, likewise.

Comment: @Ruks sorry for not explaining it that well, basically the user inputs a number or a string, next he chooses the operator, if it's "=" the user chooses the value of the string, next, the user adds the string(if they chose a string) and a number so the input would be A + 5, and the output would be 10

Comment: @bigbroin *basically the user inputs a number or a string* -- Which means that the user enters a string, and *you* have to decide whether the string is a valid number or not by parsing the string.  That's already been mentioned, but it bears repeating.  For some reason, you believe this is built-in already for you, but it isn't.

Comment: ok, got it, just parse

Comment: @bigbroin Before you do anything else, you need to decide exactly what are all the options the user has in entering the expression.  The one thing you don't want to do is write all of this code, and then realize you need to add what can be entered (maybe parentheses, etc.).  Right now, the way you wrote the code, it would be impossible to add a feature without having to rewrite most, if not everything, from scratch. just to add the new functionality  There are formal ways by writing a grammar and a parser that follows the grammar, but maybe you are not sophisticated at this point to do that.

Comment: How is it condescending?  Expression evaluators that are not written to follow a grammar, but instead are adhoc and off-the-cuff, will always need to be rewritten if a new feature is added.   This is part of computer science, it has nothing to do with condescension.  I am giving you solid advice -- if you ever have to add anything, then the proper way to write these type of programs is to write the grammar on paper first, and then write a parser (recursive descent, LALR, etc.) that follows the grammar.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but maybe you are not sophisticated at this point to do that. that line is a bit condescending, but overall I agree with your points, I'm not gonna learn what grammar is tho lmao

Comment: Writing parsers requires experience -- it isn't something you can just jump into if you don't have it yet -- that's what I meant by "sophistication at this point".  Another alternative is to use the shunting-yard algorithm for expression evaluation.  But either way, expression evaluators are tricky, but only get easier by using the formal techniques mentioned.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i found a solution:   std::stoi, that should work with vectors

Comment: Remember that `std::stoi` can throw an exception if the input isn't a valid integer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, so there's no way for me to do this at my current skill level?

Comment: You need to first, in a more formal way, describe the **exact** types of expressions that will be expected to be entered by the user.  You can't decide later what may be entered -- you have to be all-in right now as to every type of expression that is expected.  That's the only way to write the code going forward, because again, you don't want to write this code, and then later say "oh yeah, I forgot about that', and then get into the situation I mentioned.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i expect the user to enter strings or ints

Comment: What about the operations such as `+`?  Do you expect `/`?  `%`?  What about the `=` sign?  What about `abc - xyz = 0`?   What if the `=` sign appears in the wrong place? 
 You see why a formal description is required?

Comment: ya i expect the int or string first, then the operator, then an int